# MVC how to connector one model to two others

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need some help understanding how to create a model that links with two other models.

I have three models:

```
public class RequiredPower
{
  public int RequiredPowerID { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field cannot be empty!")]
  [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "This name is too long. Max. 35 characters allowed!")]
  [Display(Name = "Name:")]

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public int Position { get; set; }
}

public class RequiredFuses
{
  public int RequiredFusesID { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage ="This field cannot be empty!")]
  [MaxLength(25,ErrorMessage ="This name is too long. Max. 25 characters allowed!")]
  [Display(Name="Fuse:")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PowerConnector
{
  public int PowerConnectorID { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required!")]
  [Display(Name = "Name:")]
  [StringLength(45, ErrorMessage = "The name is too long, only 45 characters allowed!")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "The name is too long, only 150 characters allowed!")]
  [Display(Name = "Image file name:")]
  [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
  public string ImageName { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that one RequiredPower can have multiple PowerConnector and multiple RequiredFuses.

On the View I have one textbox to enter the name of the RequiredPower, a selection list for connectors and a selection list for fuses.
The selection lists are multiple checkbox lists and deliver a string of the choosen IDs like "1,2,3,".

No how to get that in the database?
I can add the new requiredPower, get the ID and then seperately create the records in the other two tables with the RequiredPowerID as the relation, but should it not be easier with EntityFramework?

What am I missing here?

Comment: how does your entity models looks like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF, you can define one-to-many relations by using virtual collections (you can see [more here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/entity-framework-code-first-relations)):

```
public class RequiredPower
{
    public int RequiredPowerID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field cannot be empty!")]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "This name is too long. Max. 35 characters allowed!")]
    [Display(Name = "Name:")]

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PowerConnector> PowerConnectors { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequiredFuses> RequiredFuses { get; set; }
}
```

With that, you can add PowerConnectors/RequiredFuses to a RequiredPower and save at once:

```
var somePower = new RequiredPower() {
    Name = 'somePower'   
};
var oneConnector = new PowerConnector() {
    Name = 'oneConnector'   
};

somePower.PowerConnectors.add(oneConnector);
somePower.SaveChanges(); // << this will create somePower and oneConnector in your database
```

Comment: Ok, got it. This was actually how I was doing it, almost, but the same record was overwritten everytime because I didn't instantiate a new class for each connector and fuse. THanks!!